# how to Create Stored Procedure with database migration in Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, stored-procedures, entity-framework-migrations

I am using migration to create my database model. I already created all tables by overriding OnModelCreating as bellow.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder modelBuilder){
modelBuilder.Entity<AccessLevel>().Map(c =>
{
    .ToTable("AccessLevel", "HelpSystem");
    c.Properties(p => new
        {
            p.Id,
            p.Name,
            p.Description
        });
}).HasKey(x => x.Id);
modelBuilder.Entity<AccessLevel>().Property(x => x.Id).HasColumnAnnotation("DatabaseGenerated", DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);}
```

Now I want to create Stored Procedure to my database like this. How can I do it?

This is the Sql Script of my Stored Procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [HelpSystem].[sp_GetLanguageContentByObject] @InfoObjectId AS BIGINT AS
SELECT  io.Id InfoObjectId ,
io.Name InfoObject ,
cc.Id ComChannelId ,
cc.Name ComChannel ,
cc2.Id ContentCategoryId ,
cc2.Name ContentCategory ,
c.Id ContentId ,
c.Name ContentName ,
c.Description ,
c.AuthorPartyId ,
c.DefaultLanguageId ,
c3.CultureCode DefaultLanguage ,
lc.Id LanguageContentId ,
lc.LanguageId ,
c2.CultureCode Language ,
lc.Title ,
lc.Content FROM    HelpSystem.InfoPointInfoObject ipio
    JOIN HelpSystem.InfoObject io ON io.Id = ipio.InfoObjectId
    JOIN HelpSystem.InfoPointComChannel ipcc ON ipcc.InfoPointId = ipio.InfoPointId
    JOIN HelpSystem.ComChannel cc ON cc.Id = ipcc.ComChannelId
    JOIN HelpSystem.InfoPointContent ipc ON ipc.InfoPointId = ipcc.InfoPointId
    JOIN HelpSystem.Content c ON c.Id = ipc.ContentId
    JOIN HelpSystem.ContentCategory cc2 ON cc2.Id = c.ContentCategoryId
    JOIN HelpSystem.LanguageContent lc ON lc.ContentId = ipc.ContentId
    JOIN Localization.Culture c2 ON lc.LanguageId = c2.Id
    JOIN Localization.Culture c3 ON c.DefaultLanguageId = c3.Id WHERE ipio.InfoObjectId = @InfoObjectId AND (ipio.ExpireDateTime IS NULL OR ipio.ExpireDateTime > GETUTCDATE()) AND (ipcc.ExpiredDateTime IS NULL OR ipcc.ExpiredDateTime > GETUTCDATE()) AND (ipc.ExpiredDateTime IS NULL OR ipc.ExpiredDateTime > GETUTCDATE())
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write the stored procedure code directly on an instance of your dbcontext using the [`ExecuteSqlCommand` API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.executesqlcommand(v=vs.113).aspx) like this:

```
_dataContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("stored procedure sql");
```

You can also use the `CreateStoredProcedure` function to create stored procedure directly from the `DbMigration` file. [CreateStoredProcedure API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.migrations.dbmigration.createstoredprocedure(v=vs.113).aspx)

There is **no** extension method on the `modelBuilder` that will let you create stored procedures.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. This is helpful for me.. :)